# How to work with video in selenium-webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some videos and I want to test their with automation.

Could you tell, how does `selenium-webdriver` work with video?

How does it recognize it?

Comment: Hi there, it might be better to ask these kind of questions on specific part of the StackExchange - http://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Test their … what … with automation? And what video? Flash? `<video>`?

Comment: I need to test if are videos on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can test if the correct elements are in the DOM for video. You won't really be able to interact with the video with Selenium. You many need to record the network traffic to check the relevant items are being downloaded or if they 404.

Comment: Thanks guys for answers. Now i have some updates. I use FlashSelenium but this <object> doesn't have id. Can you advise my smth?

Answer (score 1):

I use WebdriverJS to click on youtube video.

I have tested the methods below and found them to work.

```
.click("#videoid")
.click("iframe:hover")
.click(".classname")
```

This of course is a little surprising as Selenium is not supposed to work with flash...